# MySQL - able to access database after deleting .frm and .ibd files

Tags: php, mysql, frm

I have a MySQL server which is running with out any error. Accidentally i removed all  .ibd and .frm files. But server is not throwing any error. It continue data insert and all operations even using command line.

I found that its using ibdata files temporarily to stored and access the records.

If i try to access all records it show no records found. and it show no tables available for 'show tables' but it doesn't throw any error message if i access using particular table name

How do i over come this scenario. If any .ibd or .frm file is deleted it should throw error if i access the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `CHECK TABLE my_table EXTENDED;`

Edit:

`REPAIR TABLE tbl_name EXTENDED` should help you to bring back corrupted data. Please make a backup of the table itself and the whole database first.

Comment: It's return error.  But during select / insert / update / Delete it doesn't throw any error. 

Is there a way to instruct MySQL server to the flush the records directly in to the table file. Like in my.cnf or any arguments during startup

Comment: I just edited my answer to add the REPAIR TABLE statement... There is however a FLUSH statement which closes all open tables, pointers, etc. Link to it is right here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html